# How to implement custom login function and auth in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, session, django-views, local-storage

I have created a new model named AppUser in the sqllite db through Django and i dont want use the default django administration user model for my app login system. 
I ve implemented a login view function (below code) and the point where i am stuck is that i want to store the matched username as a local storage variable in the form of session,cookie,etc and later i want to access them to check whether the user is logged in or not by getting the session value in all my rest views/templates.

I need help that what will be the best way to do so. below is my current login view function

LOGIN.PY

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import AppUser
from .forms import AppUserForm
from django.utils.timezone import now as timezone_now

def login_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        curtime = timezone_now()
        form = AppUserForm(request.POST)
        if AppUser.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).exists():
            AppUser.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).update(checklogin=1, lastlogin=curtime)
            request.session['username'] = username //HERE I WANT TO SAVE THE VALUE LOCALLY
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return login(request)
```

Comment: Django's `contrib.auth` app is very highly customisable - you can provide your own custom `User` model, auth backend etc etc - so there's really no good reason not to use it. And there are _a lot_ of good reasons to use it instead of reinventing the proverbial squared wheel. Correct, secure auth is far from trivial, and what you show of your implementation is a complete security disaster.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you help me with some code regarding contrib.auth

Comment: That's not how SO works. First you read the doc and try to implement things by yourself, then you ask for help on a specific issue if and when the need arises.